# OpenFileDialog, I want to use If-Else Statement than Using Try-Catch - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How can I do an If-Else Statement on a OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() like this?

```
Dim MsgRegisterComplete As Integer
        MsgRegisterComplete = MsgBox("Sample", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Message Box")

        If MsgRegisterComplete = vbYes Then

        ElseIf MsgRegisterComplete = vbNo Then

        End If
```

Because I'm currently using try-catch which has flaws on it, like when I selected a picture already to be opened in a single instance of debugging. It wouldn't do any Catch Statements anymore, Unlike the If-Else Statement shown above, I do think It would work much better with OpenFileDialog.

Here is my Current Code on OpenFileDialog

```
 Dim strFileName As String

    OFDViewEditUpdateForm.InitialDirectory = "d:\"
    OFDViewEditUpdateForm.Title = "Select Picture"
    OFDViewEditUpdateForm.Filter = "JPEG images|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.png"
    OFDViewEditUpdateForm.ShowDialog()

    Try
        strFileName = OFDViewEditUpdateForm.FileName
        PBUserImage.Image = Image.FromFile(strFileName)
        LBDUserImageLink.Text = strFileName
    Catch
        MsgBox("No selected image has been made")
    End Try
```

How can I convert this try-catch statements to if-else statements like the code given above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the return value of [OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim strFileName As String

OFDViewEditUpdateForm.InitialDirectory = "d:\"
OFDViewEditUpdateForm.Title = "Select Picture"
OFDViewEditUpdateForm.Filter = "JPEG images|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.png"
if (OFDViewEditUpdateForm.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
  strFileName = OFDViewEditUpdateForm.FileName
  ' Do whatever else you want to do
Else
  MsgBox("No selected image has been made")
End If
```